# Online learning to maximize profit

Tags: regression, time-series, machine-learning, neural-networks, stochastic-processes

I have a software which takes input as investment and gives the output as return on a particular stock. Now profit metric $x_i$ is defined as the ratio of return $g_i$ to maximum possible return $g_{max}$ at $i^{th}$ period of time.

so $x_i = g_i / g_{max}$

$g_{max}$ is constant for any period but varies from stock to stock. 
Return for a particular stock at $i_{th}$ period is $g_i$ which depends on the investment $s_i$ for that period.
The relation between $g_i$ and $s_i$ varies from one period to other period.

The **question** is how to decide $s_i$ based on $s_{i-1}$ and $g_{i-1}$ in order to maximize $x_i$ for a particular stock . Is it possible to build an online learning mechanism to decide the value of $s_i$ based on previous data.

[note : $ 0 < g_i \leq g_{max}$ , $ s_{min} \leq s_i \leq s_{max}$ , $i_{th}$ time period is fixed ,in this case it's six months ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an "online learning algorithm", which will try to improve itself during some kind of environmental simulation instead of preparing training data in form of $(x_i,y_i)$, then this looks like a classical use case of [reinforcement learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinforcement_learning), with input values $s_{i-1}, g_{i-1}$ and some current stock info $data_i$, with reward $g_i$. This is quite wide branch of  machine learning, choice of particular method/algorithm is strongly data dependent. The most common approaches in reinforcement learning are Temporal Difference Learning and Q-learning, I suggest to look this things up.